# Comparing old and new prices in a bootstrap thumbnail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

As can be seen from the code below I am dynamically generating thumbnails using the template in `var sProductTemplate`. The thhumbnails are populated via ajax request which is getting the information from a json file.

My task is to compare the current price in the thumbnail vs the updated price in the json(if such) and display a green arrow in the thumbnail if the new price is higher than the old. If the new price is lower then the old one then I must display a red arrow.

**My problem** is that I cannot really get to this point, since I cannot figure out how to save the old price and then compare it to the new price for each thumbnail.

Since each thumbnail has a unique id the i've written this code to get the price from the dom by the thumbnail's id's :

```
var sPriceInDom = Number($("#product-id-"+sProductId+" .product-price").text());
```

But, of course, this gives me the last price and I cannot really compare it to the old price, since it is replaced by the new price.

If I place this code right after the ajax request, then it gives me just zeroes, since the thumbnail is dynamically generated and it has to be populated first.

Does anyone have an idea how can I keep the old price and compare it to the lastly updated one, so I can calculate the difference?

Here is all the neccesary code :

```
var sProductTemplate = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> \
                                <div class="thumbnail"> \
                                <div id="product-id-{{product-id}}" class="product"> \
                                  <img class="imgProduct" src="{{product-icon}}" alt="idiot forgot icon"> \
                                  <div class="caption"> \
                                    <h3>{{product-name}}</h3> \
                                    <div class="product-price">{{product-price}}</div> \
                                    <i {{arrow-updown}}></i> \
                                  </div> \
                                </div> \
                              </div>';
getProducts();
function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
          "url":'get-products.php',
          "method":"get",
          "dataType":"text",
          "cache":false
        }).done( function( jData ){
          var jProducts=JSON.parse(jData);

         jProducts.forEach( function( jProduct ){
            var sProductId = jProduct.id;
            var sProductName = jProduct.name;
            var sProductBrand = jProduct.brand;
            var sProductPrice = jProduct.price;
            lastPrice = sProductPrice;
            var sPriceInDom = Number($("#product-id-"+sProductId+" .product-price").text());
            console.log(sPriceInDom + " DOM");

            var arrowUP ='class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"';
            var arrowDOWN ='class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"';

              var sTempProduct = sProductTemplate;
              sTempProduct = sTempProduct.replace("{{product-id}}", sProductId);
              sTempProduct = sTempProduct.replace("{{product-icon}}", "http://image.flaticon.com/teams/1-freepik.jpg");
              sTempProduct = sTempProduct.replace("{{product-name}}", sProductBrand);
              sTempProduct = sTempProduct.replace("{{product-price}}", sProductPrice);

              sTempProduct = sTempProduct.replace("{{arrow-updown}}",arrowUP);
              $("#lblDisplayProducts").append(sTempProduct);

            })

        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue illustrates another great reason why the DOM should really not be used to store data (see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308188/storing-data-in-the-dom)). Think of the DOM as a way to reflect the current state of the data, but not as the data store itself.

It is better practice to store the data in a Javascript object of some kind and then you can compare previous and incoming values far more easily. The [KnockoutJS](http://knockoutjs.com) framework is a wonderful example of storing objects locally with dynamic data binding from the Javascript data to the DOM. [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) provides similar separation of concerns.

Overall it is better to conform to the MVC pattern where the data model isn't "stored" as part of the DOM.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input. I will have a look at that discussion. Otherwise, I know that usind MVC would be desireble here, but this code is part of a uni class assignment, and I am not allowed to use any design patterns or frameworks. :)